# Twilio can't find xml on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am integrating twilio click to call into my rails project.

Everything works fine however the url: in my twilio controller cannot be found on heroku. However, it can be found if you navigate to it in a browser. The phone dials but the voice says "Sorry a problem has occurred, good bye." If I change the url to an external xml file it works fine, just doesn't recognize this particular one. So I'm lead to believe that the controller etc works fine.

**twillio_controller.rb**

```
  def call

      @full_phone = current_user.phone
      @partial_phone = @full_phone.last(-1)
      @connected_number = "+61" + @partial_phone


      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new @@twilio_sid, @@twilio_token
      # Connect an outbound call to the number submitted
      @call = @client.calls.create(
        :from => @@twilio_number,
        :to => @connected_number,
        :url => 'http://besttradies.herokuapp.com/mytradies/connect.xml', # Fetch instructions from this URL when the call connects
      )
      @msg = { :message => 'Phone call incoming!', :status => 'ok' }

  end

  def connect
    # Our response to this request will be an XML document in the "TwiML"
    # format. Our Ruby library provides a helper for generating one
    # of these documents
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say 'If this were a real click to call implementation, you would be connected to an agent at this point.', :voice => 'alice'

    end
    render text: response.text
  end
```

Comment: Figured it out. Routes for connect needed to be POST and I also had to add skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token to the twilio controller as it was behind membership doors.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

The OP solved in the comments above:

> Figured it out. Routes for connect needed to be POST and I also had to
>   add skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token to the [twilio
>   controller](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/ruby/rails) as it was behind membership doors.